# React Native error pod install, Debian 10

Tags: ios, linux, react-native, cocoapods, debian-buster

React Native 0.62,
OS Debian 10 Buster

I'm trying to run ios emulator for React Native project. For that I run 'pod install'  within ios folder and caught error:

```
...

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

...

checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc...  -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/usr/bin/bash: line 24: xcrun: command not found
/usr/bin/bash: line 24: xcrun: command not found
/home/user/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/home/user/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/home/user/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to run Xcode, iOS Simulators or, as you can see, CocoaPods on Linux. CocoaPods, while itself a ruby gem, still depends on Xcode command line tools (eg. `xcrun`, which is reported not found in your output above).

Perhaps there are virtualisation options - not something I've tried myself.

Comment: I installed the CocoaPods from `brew install cocoapods` on Debian. Maybe already is any solution to fix this bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a bug.

Comment: Could you to recommend any cloud with MacOS for testing app, please?

Comment: Not something I have any experience with - could be worth asking another question on this or another forum.